# KeyError: 'MYSQL_HOST'

Tags: python, flask, flask-mysql

I'm getting this error upon sending a POST request to my REST API. Anyone know what this means? I am using flask mysql instead of SQL alchemy

- Detected change in 'C:\Users\User-PC\Desktop\Python API\models.py', reloading
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 114-398-217
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
  {'username': 'ah', 'password': 'oh'}
  127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2021 16:54:36] "←[35m←[1mPOST /api/auth/login HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -
  Traceback (most recent call last):

```
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
        response = self.handle_exception(e)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
        return original_handler(e)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 38, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
        return original_handler(e)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 38, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 468, in wrapper
        resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 89, in view
        return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 583, in dispatch_request
        resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\Desktop\Python API\resources.py", line 22, in post
        user = User.fetch_userid_from_db(post_data['username'])
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\Desktop\Python API\models.py", line 24, in fetch_userid_from_db
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_mysqldb\__init__.py", line 94, in connection
        ctx.mysql_db = self.connect
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_mysqldb\__init__.py", line 43, in connect
        if current_app.config['MYSQL_HOST']:
    KeyError: 'MYSQL_HOST'
    {'username': 'ah', 'password': 'oh'}
    127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2021 16:55:18] "←[35m←[1mPOST /api/auth/login HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
        response = self.handle_exception(e)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
        return original_handler(e)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 38, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
        return original_handler(e)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 38, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 468, in wrapper
        resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 89, in view
        return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 583, in dispatch_request
        resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\Desktop\Python API\resources.py", line 22, in post
        user = User.fetch_userid_from_db(post_data['username'])
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\Desktop\Python API\models.py", line 24, in fetch_userid_from_db
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_mysqldb\__init__.py", line 94, in connection
        ctx.mysql_db = self.connect
      File "C:\Users\User-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_mysqldb\__init__.py", line 43, in connect
        if current_app.config['MYSQL_HOST']:
    KeyError: 'MYSQL_HOST'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `MYSQL_HOST` is not define. You should revise your DB config class.
By the way, make sure not to post any real name or password, I guess 'ah' and 'oh' are not real.

Comment: Here is the DB Config (with sensitive info removed): 
```app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config[MYSQL_HOST] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'mydb'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'    ```

Comment: You missed the ' ' in the field. Use ```app.config['MYSQL_HOST']``` instead.

Comment: apologies for not adding it in there. I tried it and it did not fix the issue

Comment: Do you get the same error when using `app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'` ? Please provide a bit more information.